# Getting 400 response when i try for POST request

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, cxf

I am using CXF and my bean is as follows

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    protected Long Id;

    @XmlElement(name = "students")
    protected Set<String> students;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

When i try to use the below request it works

```
    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    public String getCounts(JAXBElement<Test> jaxFilters) {
        Test filter = jaxFilter.getValue();
        //Some logic
    }
```

But when i use the below request i am getting 400 error

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
public String getCounts(JAXBElement<List<Test>> jaxFilters) {
    List<Test> filter = jaxFilter.getValue();
    //Some logic
}
```

Can someone help me how to write the Post request to accept for the collection of jaxb beans as body in the post request.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste the request body!

Comment: Here it goes [{"id":"7336","students":["Q1","Q2"]}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Actually in POJO class instead of @XmlRootElement annotated with @XMLType and removed wrapping of JAXBElement in Rest call.